# Python Django how to retrieve specific objects

Tags: python, html, django, web

I've got this Post model at the moment:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

If I've got different parts of a website (or a forum rather) that contain different posts, e.g. Discussion about basketball, and Discussion about football, if I wanted to return just posts concerning basketball or just posts concerning football, is the easiest way to just make a specific basketball_post model/football_post model or is there a more efficient way? Should I perhaps be storing the values differently?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has a really good tutorial. It is about making a Poll app. In the first chapter the thing you want is discussed. It is about a `Question` that can have multiple `Choice`s.:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The foreignKey creates a relation between two models. The same can be done for a blog:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category) # This is the important part.
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

The ForeignKey relation lets you do really nice things:

```
basketball_posts = Post.objects.filter(category_title='Basketball')
```

But before we all tell you how it is done, I really recommend to do the tutorial. It introduces you to all important Django concepts: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/

**Update**

If you have a fixed set of categories that are not likely to change, than you can hardcode them and use field choices:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    FOOTBALL = 'F' # Variable name and db_value
    CRICKET = 'C'
    INTRODUCTION = 'I'
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (FOOTBALL, 'Soccer'), # Variable name and display value
        (CRICKET, 'Cricket'),
        (INTRODUCTION, 'Hello my name is'),
    )
    category = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                                      choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES,
                                      default=INTRODUCTION)
    ...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices

One of the advantages of this 'choice machinery' over a CharField without pre defined choices is that you are sure what values end up in your database. This lets you query them, without worrying if your data is sane:

```
Post.objects.filter(category=Post.CRICKET)
```

Use the extra table if you need the freedom to create new categories in the future. Use field choices if you don't want (or need) that freedom.

Comment: Similarly to the answers below, doesn't this require the user to input information into Category?

If a user clicks on the "Basketball" page and attempts to post, to have the Category of that post automatically become Basketball? 

If not, then wouldn't multiple classes be appropriate, otherwise how would you differentiate between posts in "Basketball" section of the website or "Music" section as some posts in "Basketball" may discuss things that are music related and vice versa.

Comment: No, you can present the user with a single textfield form and set the category field when handeling the post data and saving it. This can be anything. Maybe the category is set according to the url where the post came from: `/blogs/footbal/add/`? It is up to you what happens. It has little to do with your db design.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to just add a field which makes the post relevant to that certain topic:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
   body = models.TextField()
   date = models.DateTimeField()
   type = models.CharField(max_length=20) #<--- new field: e.g 'basketball','hockey'..

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.title
```

example query:

```
#basketball posts
qs = Post.objects.filter(type__icontains="basketball")
```

then you dont need to have multiple models which also would be redundant.

Comment: why `icontains`? why model the types as a text field? What advantage does having a text field have over having m2m or FK relationship with another model?

Comment: Doesn't this just return all the posts which contain Basketball? In order to narrow down certain posts don't you have to be a lot more specific, at which point it would be easier to just give it its own model?

If I've got an Introduce Yourself page and then a Basketball Discussion page, the relevant posts are going to be very different to each other and I don't want to return a post in "Basketball Discussion" just because it contains the word basketball because it might be part of someone's introduction post, so in order to get around that isn't it better to make two separate models?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of the posts are in the same format, you could add another field to your model like "type".  Different discussion forums could send a different values for that field when the post is added.

```
type = models.CharField(max_length=140, choices=['Football', 'Basketball', 'Baseball'])
```

Storing this would make it easy to filter which posts are which.

```
Post.objects.filter(type = 'Football')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that one post can be about only one sport, the better approach would be to have a foreign key relation between a model that stores data about a post with another model that stores the data about sports.

Something like this

```
class Sport(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    sport = models.ForeignKey(Sport)        

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

This gives you the advantage of isolating the 'Sport' and the 'Post' models.You can add as many sports as you want, without any posts referring to it.

One more advantage is that you can add relevant information to the relevant models. 
Eg:Suppose you want to add the information about "how many players are there in a team for sport x?". You can easily achieve this by adding a field "number_of_players" in the 'Sport' model without affecting the 'Post' model. 
If you had to do this in one model, 'Post', then it would create lot of issues in terms of data consistency and other undesirable things.

Also, the query will look something like this:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(sport__name = "Basketball")
```

PS:If your requirement is that a post can be tagged to multiple sports, then you can use ManyToMany field instead of a simple foreign key.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, if my Forum has say 3 or 4 different groups like: 
"Sports", "Music", "Art" 
say and in each of these, you can discuss whatever you like so a post in Sports could be titled "Basketball" and a post in Art could also be titled "Basketball", how could you then differentiate it so that only posts posted in Art would be returned. 

If you introduce a foreign key, then doesn't that require the person posting to write in "Basketball" in the sports category every time? 

Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: I think the example I gave below was bit more coherent:


If I've got an Introduce Yourself page and then a Basketball Discussion page, the relevant posts are going to be very different to each other and I don't want to return a post in "Basketball Discussion" just because it contains the word basketball because it might be part of someone's introduction post, so in order to get around that isn't it better to make two separate models?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.And your second comment confused me.I have already suggested two models.Can you please give me concrete examples of your requirements?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it well. I found my answer though in the comments provided by allcaps above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could assign your posts tags or category, and filter on those.

If you use the model approach what happens when you add more sports? You'll need manually add the sports in your code,  using a tags or category approach allows you to handle it in the db, and would then allow you to filter on the tags/categories in your system